# Could not load library cublasLt64_10.dll. Error code 126

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

```
2022-02-23 14:32:16.058080: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-02-23 14:32:18.937118: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1510] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1336 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce MX250, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
2022-02-23 14:32:33.728880: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
Could not load library cublasLt64_10.dll. Error code 126
Please make sure cublasLt64_10.dll is in your library path!
```

I am a student and I am trying to use GPU to learn deep learning.
I already had setup cuda 11.6 but since it was giving me some errors i dowloaded 11.5 and now having this error continuously plus i am unable to find the file that is specifid in the error code please help me i have already wasted 2 days in fixing it

Comment: Which tensorflow version are you using? What commands did you use to install it? Did you install `tensorflow-gpu`? What is the output of `nvidia-smi` and `nvcc --version`?

Comment: I am using TensorFlow == 2.6.0.

Output of nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because you are not:
 a) running as an administrator or
 b) there is not at least one TCC device in the system

Output of nvcc -- version

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Feb_10_19:03:51_Pacific_Standard_Time_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.112
Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.30978841_0

These are the outputs that I am getting please help me!

Comment: Are you on Windows? Also, what exactly did you run to install everything?

Comment: I am extremely sorry here are the correct outputs
Actually nvdia-smi gave that output beacause i turned off my drivers so as my program could atleast run on CPU

Here are the correct outputs

Answer (score 1):

Can you  cd into the folder,and find cudart64_101.dll, copy it into c:/window/system path.
Also ensure your  python installation is not from the windows. Download the python installation file from the official site.

And verify version compatibility from here :- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows

You may also want to verify [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40804)